# MutliTouch Works on iPad Simulator, but not devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios-simulator

I know variations of this question have been asked before, but I am working on an app that uses two separate touches to operate. The app works perfectly on the iPad simulator, but only allows me to use one touch when running on the device. When I start a second touch, the app stops. Any thought/suggestions?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Below is the code for assigning the different touches to their respective synthesis variables:

```
 //Csound varaibles assigned depending on touch location
    -(void)sendValueYFromOneTouch:(Float32)valueY object:(UInt16)objectID{

        if (objectID == 1)
        {
            _grainValue = 100 + valueY * 900;
    //        printf("grainValue is %f", _grainValue);
        }
        else if (objectID == 2)
        {
            _densityValue = 1 + valueY * 9999 -1;
            printf("densityValue is %f", _densityValue);
        }
    }

-(void)sendValueXFromOneTouch:(Float32)valueX object:(UInt16)objectID
{
    if (objectID == 1)
    {
           _offsetValue= valueX * 20000;
//            printf("offsetValue is %f", _offsetValue);
    }
    else if (objectID == 2)
    {
            _durationValue= 0.05 + valueX * 0.95;
          printf("durationValue is %f", _durationValue);
    }
}
```

When it runs on the simulator, it works perfectly, but for some reason not on the iPad itself.

Comment: Have you tried adding a breakpoint to see why the apps crashing?

Comment: Or pause the app when it 'stops' to see what it's doing.

Comment: what you have done?,put some code..

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing , you should include `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` in your header file.

And further use ->

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
return YES;
```

}

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch{
return YES;
```

}